# Getting empty matches when using regular expression \d*

Tags: javascript, regex

```
string = 'Hello _1234_ world _4567_';
string.match(/(\d*)/gi);
//,,,,,,,1234,,,,,,,,,,4567,,
```

If I change regext to have \d+ then I get proper values: 1234 and 4567. Why in the first case I am getting all those empty matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means 0 or more. `+` means 1 or more.

`\d*` matches the empty space between each character because this is the empty string, i.e. zero digits. When you use `\d+` the empty string is no longer a valid match so you don't get these extra matches.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have (\d*) which means capture every time there is 0 or more digits, which means 
every character (even some non visible characters like a linefeed) matches.

With \d+, you are saying match where there are 1 or more digits.